# Delete file in hard drive root folder using recovery disk

Tags: system-recovery

I made changes to my `xorg.conf` file in `/etc/X11/` after backing it up.

Some bad things happened and now I cannot access tty or the logon screen.

The only way is via a recovery USB drive.

How can I give permissions to the kubuntu default user on the recovery drive to delete the new and restore the old file? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try editing the kernel command line in (probably) Grub. Add `1` or `emergency`.

Comment: Thank you. I'll reserve this for the next time I encounter the issue. For some reason, the system overwrote the old file on reboot (After about 20 or so reboots). Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can boot into your regular system for fixing this problem without starting the X server by editing the kernel command line in (probably) Grub. Add `1` or `emergency`.